# The process of creating new openGL versions?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, nvidia, video-card

After reading some of this online book, http://learnopengl.com/book/offline%20learnopengl.pdf, some questions started to pop up in my head concerning how exactly newer versions of openGL are created. According to this online read, graphics card manufacturers are responsible for creating newer versions of openGL. So say Nvidia develops (hypothetically) a GTX 700 series graphics card with openGL version 4.3. After this they decide to develop a 900 series graphics card with some optimizations to the implementation of openGL. After the cards are complete and the optimizations made they then label these new optimizations for openGL as openGL 4.4. Is my example here correct in how new versions are created? Also, if so, then what does the kronos group (the developers of openGL) actually do? Are they responsible for making sure the new versions of openGL match required specifications?

Comment: Well, right now it doesn't really matter, because 4.5 is very likely to be the *last* OpenGL version ever.

Comment: @Jason: Bartek probably means that Vulkan is expected to replace OpenGL. However this is not yet entirely true. First Vulkan is much more low-level API so there might be interest in implementing OpenGL as a higher-level wrapper of Vulkan, and second is that OpenGL still receives new extensions and I suspect that there might be future OpenGL release incorporating some of those extensions into the core.

Comment: I see. I'll have to look this up. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, nVidia does not unilaterally label their modifications as the next-gen OpenGL.

Instead, what happens is that each vendor improves the design of their architecture and exposes the new features through OpenGL *extensions*. Those extensions might be vendor specific like `GL_NV_bindless_texture` or developed by collaborative effort of multiple vendors, like `GL_EXT_direct_state_access`. If multiple vendors are interested in implementing the extension or the extension is already implemented by multiple vendors then it might be promoted to an ARB extension, possibly after some modifications (e.g. `GL_ARB_bindless_texture` and `GL_ARB_direct_state_access`). Eventually some of the extensions are decided to be promoted to be part of the core OpenGL specification, so for example `GL_ARB_direct_state_access` became an integral part of OpenGL 4.5, whereas `GL_ARB_bindless_texture` might one day be integrated into a future OpenGL version.

The Khronos group is responsible for maintaining the extension registry, promoting and reviewing the extensions into the ARB status, and evolution of the core OpenGL specification.